# Axios and Angular

Tags: angular, rest, axios

Trying to figure out how to make an axios import and use in an Angular cli, base scaffolding.

I didn't find any docs for this.

I found this 
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-use-your-own-http-library-b45e51b3525e

what he suggests does not apply. the Cli breaks on adding any of his code bits.

Any insight on how to do a basic post api call in Angular?

best I got is (the angular native approach) :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'prouuuut';
  posts = [];
  errors = [];
  constructor(private http: Http){
  }

  fetchAll(){
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/repositories')
      .then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data.entry
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
```

inside app.component.ts but I already have :

[image]

Comment: You should import Axios as any other third-party library, with `import`. The approach described in the article is nonsense, just because `Http` is specific class and it isn't Axios. Even if it's possible to replace it with `{provide: Http, useValue: axios}`, it makes no sense and will fail type checks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Most probably using Axios's concrete class instead of Angular's Http concrete class is not a valid approach since each of these classes would have a different interface.

You need to

1. npm install @types/axios
2. import axios as you import any other third-party library in typescript

Note that it is recommended to use Angular's Http Client Module

From axios github page:

> axios is heavily inspired by the $http service provided in Angular.
>   Ultimately axios is an effort to provide a standalone $http-like
>   service for use outside of Angular"

Angular's (Angular 2+) Http
client is more powerful than Angular JS's Http client, so I could not
think of a reason that requires you to be making this switch

Comment: Angular http client is kind of slow sometimes. It's the actual reason I personally want to try out other http clients...