# I'm not able to use Axios in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm an absolute beginner to TypeScript. In my first hello world project I got completely confused with typescript modules.
I'm trying to use Axios to get some data from [a fake json api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) but the problem is that my IDE isn't able to find Axios from node modules.
Things that i've done so far.

1- First I made **index.ts** file

```
import axios from "axios";
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2";

axios.get(url).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

2- Then I installed **axios** via npm which created the node-modules folder

```
npm install axios
```

3- I got the api result by this command in cmd

```
ts-node index.ts
```

This is compiled js

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var axios_1 = __importDefault(require("axios"));
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2";
axios_1.default.get(url).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

so far everything is good and data is shown in cmd. but everything is different in browsers(Chrome, Firefox and Edge). When I link compiled js to my browser I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I found that i have to change settings in tsconfig file from commonjs to requirejs but when i change the `"module": "commonjs",` to `"module": "amd"`,   `import axios from "axios;"` turnes red in index.ts file and IDE alerts me that **cant find axios**. what I'm missing here??

I searched many websites including stackoverflow but did not find any good answer. If u need more information I mean my package,json or anything pls comment so I'll add them to this question

Comment: what browser are you using? I've seen that error in IE

Comment: @JuanCastillo almost in every browser. Firefox, Chrome and Edge.Last versions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios and Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098802/axios-and-angular)

Comment: You don't need axios with Angular

Comment: @RandyCasburn no. I'm using typescript not angular

Comment: Whoops...sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because browser doesn't recognize the commonjs output, and failed to find the axios source code.

Typescript only compile the ts code into js, but not responsible for generating bundle file. To run your code in browser, you have to use a bundler like `webpack` to transform the commonjs output into a bundle file which includes all source codes.

You can follow the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) to setup the webpack with typescript